# How to train a custom model for object detection using models/official/vision/detection?

Tags: tensorflow-model-garden

How to train a custom model for object detection using [models/official/vision/detection](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/vision/detection)?

Answer (score 0):

To train a new model, the training entry is [main.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/vision/detection/main.py).

Here are a few steps of how to add new models.

If you want to just build a simple model, say MyRetinaNet, on top of current existing components like layers, losses, existing heads, you might need to:

1. Add a config template for the new model like [this one](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/vision/detection/configs/retinanet_config.py).
2. Add a file "my_retinanet_model.py" in the modeling folder (similar to "retinanet_model.py") and implement the model.
3. Add a branch to the [factory file](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/vision/detection/modeling/factory.py) so that you can use it in [main.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/vision/detection/main.py).

If you want to add some fine-grained components like heads and backbones, then you need to add something to the [models/official/vision/detection/modeling/architecture/](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/vision/detection/modeling/architecture) folder.

1. Add a class to heads.py (for heads) or a new .py file for backbones.
2. Update the [factory.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/vision/detection/modeling/architecture/factory.py) accordingly.
3. You might also need to change [the model configs](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/vision/detection/configs/retinanet_config.py) accordingly,

For even finer-grained ops, you can add to [ops](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/vision/detection/ops) and [utils](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/vision/detection/utils).

Comment: uhh, good job asking and answering your own question! curious though, are you from an official tensorflow support group?

Comment: Yes, we seeded this question (and answer) in order to create this new tag: tensorflow-model-garden! Thanks for noticing  :-)

Comment: @TensorflowSupport, is the codebase adapted to TensorFlow 2.X versions?

Comment: @tensorflow Support, What about training the existing models with custom dataset? I have posted a question here: [maskrcnn training error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61280885/tf-models-official-vision-detection-mask-rcnn-invalid-argument-indices1-63)

Comment: @TensorflowSupport can you look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66472201/9215780) topic. You might be interested.