# tf-models: official.vision.detection Mask-RCNN Invalid argument: indices[1,63] = [1, -1] does not index into param shape [2,100,112,112]

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-model-garden

I am trying to train a Mask RCNN model based on the official MaskRCNN model present here: [tensorflow/models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/vision/detection).

Below are the steps I followed:

1. Created a tfrecord for training and validation. I have checked encoding and decoding of the tfrecords, it is working fine.
2. Set up the config file as below:

   ```yaml
   # my_maskrcnn.yaml
   train:
       train_file_pattern: "data/<dataset_name>/train/tfrecords/train.tfrecord-*"
       batch_size: 2
   eval:
       eval_file_pattern: "data/<data_set_name>/val/tfrecords/val.tfrecord-*"
       batch_size: 2
   predict:
       batch_size: 2
   architecture:
       num_classes: 2
   maskrcnn_parser:
       output_size: [512, 512]
   ```
3. Put the models/official to PYTHONPATH.
4. Ran the command for a single GPU as suggested in the documentation:

   ```sh
   python path/to/models/official/vision/detection/main.py \
       --strategy_type=one_device \
       --model_dir=models_mask_rcnn \
       --mode=train \
       --config_file="mymaskrcnn.yaml" \
       --model=mask_rcnn
   ```

But I am getting the following error:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".../models/official/vision/detection/main.py", line 255, in <module>
    app.run(main)
File ".../lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 299, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
File ".../lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 250, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
File ".../models/official/vision/detection/main.py", line 250, in main
    run()
File ".../models/official/vision/detection/main.py", line 244, in run
    callbacks=callbacks)
File ".../models/official/vision/detection/main.py", line 130, in run_executor
    save_config=True)
File ".../models/official/modeling/training/distributed_executor.py", line 482, in train
    tf.convert_to_tensor(num_steps, dtype=tf.int32))
File ".../lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 688, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
File ".../lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 741, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
File ".../lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2407, in __call__
    return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
File ".../lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1655, in _filtered_call
    self.captured_inputs)
File ".../lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1732, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
File ".../lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 598, in call
    ctx=ctx)
File ".../lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 60, in quick_execute
    inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
(0) Invalid argument:  indices[1,63] = [1, -1] does not index into param shape [2,100,112,112]
        [[{{node while/body/_241/while/maskrcnn/tf_op_layer_sample_and_crop_foreground_masks/GatherNd_4/sample_and_crop_foreground_masks/GatherNd_4}}]]
(1) Invalid argument:  indices[1,63] = [1, -1] does not index into param shape [2,100,112,112]
        [[{{node while/body/_241/while/maskrcnn/tf_op_layer_sample_and_crop_foreground_masks/GatherNd_4/sample_and_crop_foreground_masks/GatherNd_4}}]]
        [[while/body/_241/while/AddN_40/_3885]]
0 successful operations.
1 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_step_89096]

Function call stack:
train_step -> train_step
```

Where am I going wrong?